# python - replace the boolean value of a list with the values from two different lists

Tags: python, list, replace, boolean

I have one list with boolean values like

```
lyst = [True,True,False,True,False]
```

and two different lists for example like:

```
car = ['BMW','VW','Volvo']
a = ['b','c']
```

I just want to replace True with the values from `car` and False with the values from `a`.
or make a new list with the sequence from `lyst` and values from `car` and `a`.
The result should be

```
[BMW,VW,b,Volvo,c].
```

my code so far:

```
for elem1,elem2,elem3 in zip(lyst,car,a):
    subelem2=elem2
    subelem3=elem3
    if elem1 != True:
        result_list.append(subelem2)
    else: 
        result_list.append(subelem3)
```

but this creates a list match longer than 5.

How can i do this?

Comment: What if the number of `True` items in `list` is greater than the number of items in `car`? Also you should avoid using the name `list` for a variable.

Comment: @asongtoruin The same holds for `False` ofc..

Comment: It's going to be a bit controversial... as a newbie, I can assure you that when you are answering such a simple question with iter ,next or complex list comprehension, you are simple encouraging the newbie who asked the question to just copy/paste the code without attempting to understand what actually happened. These are the right way to do things, I know, and you must note them. But not before a simple answer first.

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
car = iter(car)
a = iter(a)
[next(car) if item else next(a) for item in lyst]
```

---

Ok, I couldn't help myself:

```
car = iter(car)
a = iter(a)
[(flag and next(car)) or next(a) for flag in lyst]
```

This makes use of some boolean expression features:

- a boolean `and` expression will NOT evaluate the second operand if the first operand is False
- a boolean `and` expression will return the second operand (the actual object) if both operands evaluate to True
- a boolean `or` expression will return the first object that evaluates to True

A potential problem would be if any items in `car` or `a` evaluate to False.  Also this isn't as readable as the ternary in the first solution.

But it was fun.

---

I guess I'll add that after looking at this again, I probably shouldn't have reassigned the original list names - I should have chosen something different for the iterator names.  Once exhausted, the iterators cannot be *reset* and since the list names were reassigned, the original list information is lost.

Comment: Yeah, this was my thought. I can't help but feel that there's some construct to make it nicer maybe.

Comment: @Mitch something like [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  I looked through itertools but couldn't come up with something better.

Comment: I'm with you - can't think of anything atm. Nice answer though, +1 :)

Comment: The first code works well. What is the diffence to your second code? @ wwii

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the pitfall of the `and ... or` approach (when one of the desired items may be false-ish). That used to bite a lot of people in the early days of Python, when we didn't have the ternary conditional expression, so use of the `and ... or` construction was a lot more common than it is in modern Python.

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer. Your algorithms consistently score highly on a variety of lists sizes in both Python 3 & 2. So it looks like Yuli chose well when she accepted your answer. :)

Comment: @PM` - you must have drank a lot of coffee last night (or is it morning?).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that there are the correct number of `True` and `False` entries in `lyst`, you can do this efficiently by creating iterators of the other two lists. This is more efficient than `pop`ing from the front of the lists.

```
lyst = [True, True, False, True, False]
car = ['BMW', 'VW', 'Volvo']
a = ['b', 'c']
selector = [iter(a), iter(car)]
result = [next(selector[b]) for b in lyst]
print(result)
```

**output**

```
['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
```

The `selector[b]` construction works because `False` has a numeric value of 0, and `True` has a numeric value of 1, so we can use the boolean values of `lyst` to index into the `selector` list.

---

### Timings

I decided to write a [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) script to compare the speeds of the various algorithms posted here, as well as vaultah's code from [the dupe target question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309556/merge-two-or-more-lists-with-given-order-of-merging).

To test these algorithms I've put them all into functions. To get accurate timing data `timeit` runs the function multiple times. The algorithms that use `.pop` consume the lists they pop from, so I had to add code to those functions to create copies of those lists. Obviously, that copying process slows those functions down, and in some applications it may not matter that the input data lists get destroyed, but I feel that the copying time needs to be included to fairly compare the speeds of these functions for more general use.

`timeit` measures wall clock time not CPU time, so the timings will be affected by the other processes running on the system. So when running `timeit` code it's a good idea to reduce the system load as much as possible. Ideally, you should shut down Net access, or at least avoid using your browser while the tests are running. And definitely don't listen to music or watch videos. :)

The code below runs on Python 2.6+ as well as Python 3. I tested it on Python 2.6.6 and Python 3.6.0.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

''' Merge two lists according to a list of booleans

    Given data lists `alist` and `blist`, iterate over boolean list `chooser`.
    If the current item in `chooser` is False, append the next item from `alist`
    to the output list.
    If the current item in `chooser` is True, append the next item from `blist`
    to the output list.

    See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42028606/4014959

    Speed tests of implementations by various authors
    Timing code written by PM 2Ring 2016.12.28
'''

# Python 2 / 3 compatible

from __future__ import print_function, division
from timeit import Timer
from random import seed, shuffle

seed(1234)

# The functions to test

def merge_wwii_ifelse(alist, blist, chooser):
    alist = iter(alist)
    blist = iter(blist)
    return [next(blist) if item else next(alist) for item in chooser]

def merge_wwii_andor(alist, blist, chooser):
    alist = iter(alist)
    blist = iter(blist)
    return [(flag and next(blist)) or next(alist) for flag in chooser]

def merge_PM2R_it(alist, blist, chooser):
    selector = [iter(alist), iter(blist)]
    return [next(selector[b]) for b in chooser]

def merge_PM2R_pop(alist, blist, chooser):
    alist = list(alist)
    blist = list(blist)
    return [blist.pop() if item else alist.pop() for item in reversed(chooser)][::-1]

def merge_AlexL(alist, blist, chooser):
    alist = list(alist)
    blist = list(blist)
    return [blist.pop(0) if item else alist.pop(0) for item in chooser]

def merge_Laurent(alist, blist, chooser):
    selector = {True: iter(blist), False: iter(alist)}
    return [next(selector[flag]) for flag in chooser]

def merge_Shihab(alist, blist, chooser):
    i = j = 0
    ans = []
    for v in chooser:
        if v:
            ans.append(blist[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            ans.append(alist[j])
            j += 1
    return ans

def merge_EvKounis(alist, blist, chooser):
    mapping = {True: list(blist), False: list(alist)}
    return [mapping[c].pop(0) for c in chooser]

def merge_vaultah(alist, blist, chooser):
    i1 = iter(alist)
    i2 = iter(blist)
    return [next(i2 if x else i1) for x in chooser]

funcs = (
    merge_wwii_ifelse,
    merge_wwii_andor,
    merge_PM2R_it,
    merge_PM2R_pop,
    merge_AlexL,
    merge_Laurent,
    merge_Shihab,
    merge_EvKounis,
    merge_vaultah,
)

# - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

def qdata_test():
    print('Testing all functions with the question data')
    alist, blist, chooser = (
        ['b', 'c'],
        ['BMW', 'VW', 'Volvo'], 
        [True, True, False, True, False],
    )

    expected = ['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
    print('Expected:', expected)
    for func in funcs:
        print(func.__name__, func(alist, blist, chooser) == expected)

def make_data(size):
    ''' Create two equal-sized data lists and a random chooser list '''
    a = list(range(1, size + 1))
    b = [-u for u in a]
    c = [False] * size + [True] * size
    shuffle(c)
    return a, b, c

def verify():
    results = [func(alist, blist, chooser) for func in funcs]
    first = results[0]
    return all(first == u for u in results[1:])

def time_test(loops, reps):
    ''' Print timing stats for all the functions '''
    timings = []
    for func in funcs:
        fname = func.__name__
        setup = 'from __main__ import alist, blist, chooser, ' + fname
        cmd = '{0}(alist, blist, chooser)'.format(fname)
        t = Timer(cmd, setup)
        result = t.repeat(reps, loops)
        result.sort()
        timings.append((result, fname))

    timings.sort()
    for result, fname in timings:
        print('{0:18} {1}'.format(fname, result))

qdata_test()

maxloops = 5 ** 7
for i in range(1, 7):
    size = 5 ** i
    loops, reps = maxloops // size, 3
    print('\nList size = {0}, loops = {1}'.format(size, loops))

    alist, blist, chooser = make_data(size)
    print('All functions verified', verify())

    time_test(loops, reps)
```

**Python 3 output**

```
Testing all functions with the question data
Expected: ['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
merge_wwii_ifelse True
merge_wwii_andor True
merge_PM2R_it True
merge_PM2R_pop True
merge_AlexL True
merge_Laurent True
merge_Shihab True
merge_EvKounis True
merge_vaultah True

List size = 5, loops = 15625
All functions verified True
merge_Shihab       [0.1553873940010817, 0.15573736099941016, 0.1570748160011135]
merge_vaultah      [0.19238512099946092, 0.19444048600053065, 0.19622620799964352]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.1928826420007681, 0.20096588600063114, 0.2038269639997452]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.19839437199880194, 0.19887267900048755, 0.1997791949997918]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.21258554000087315, 0.21627756400084763, 0.21734632500010775]
merge_Laurent      [0.22584542599906854, 0.22584707799978787, 0.2275525179993565]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.252919409000242, 0.2563238849998015, 0.28485306599941396]
merge_AlexL        [0.295069166999383, 0.2970452879999357, 0.3192335510011617]
merge_EvKounis     [0.3210714779997943, 0.32545770300021104, 0.3283817559986346]

List size = 25, loops = 3125
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_andor   [0.13853849199949764, 0.13861457399980281, 0.16665312800068932]
merge_vaultah      [0.1385455899999215, 0.13872790400091617, 0.13888424499964458]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.14001116700092098, 0.1411627879988373, 0.14938874099971144]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.1415618489991175, 0.14180967100037378, 0.14234910300001502]
merge_Shihab       [0.1417505749996053, 0.14575945399883494, 0.1469801869989169]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.15280632599933597, 0.1578172520003136, 0.20611876800103346]
merge_Laurent      [0.15372244299942395, 0.15373632599948905, 0.15608775699911348]
merge_AlexL        [0.19783953799924348, 0.19835066099949472, 0.19853855400106113]
merge_EvKounis     [0.21501469599934353, 0.21525065300011192, 0.21861338300004718]

List size = 125, loops = 625
All functions verified True
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10481183099909686, 0.10530150200065691, 0.1054428099996585]
merge_vaultah      [0.12480986199989275, 0.125469589000204, 0.12560611799926846]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.1248406070008059, 0.1251086979991669, 0.12896737399933045]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.1248461369996221, 0.12487849500030279, 0.1357243729999027]
merge_Shihab       [0.13901417600027344, 0.14433371599989187, 0.14757765399917844]
merge_Laurent      [0.14081091899970488, 0.14126963899980183, 0.21554046200071753]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.14273404000050505, 0.1436745359987981, 0.14957189699998708]
merge_AlexL        [0.1876233860002685, 0.18891249499938567, 0.2016287040005409]
merge_EvKounis     [0.20533967399933317, 0.2060009060005541, 0.2169854090006993]

List size = 625, loops = 125
All functions verified True
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10215267800049332, 0.10283978299958108, 0.10370849799983262]
merge_vaultah      [0.12245723900014127, 0.1226432970015594, 0.12315383100030886]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.12513774199942418, 0.12616848099969502, 0.12886606600113737]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.12801914100055, 0.12805822200061812, 0.12933381000038935]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.137118164999265, 0.13727735000065877, 0.1388498169999366]
merge_Laurent      [0.138064671000393, 0.1399875509996491, 0.1408491909987788]
merge_Shihab       [0.14056324699959077, 0.14599118399928557, 0.190011668999432]
merge_AlexL        [0.2494661869986885, 0.24949409599867067, 0.25023536899971077]
merge_EvKounis     [0.2604512350008008, 0.2616422920000332, 0.26348238600076]

List size = 3125, loops = 25
All functions verified True
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10108045999913884, 0.1956245539986412, 0.19625802900009148]
merge_vaultah      [0.1205880960005743, 0.12112638399958087, 0.12208285199994862]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.12255161999928532, 0.12333094499990693, 0.12521908300004725]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.12545375700028671, 0.12909694299924013, 0.1335049829995114]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.13350266700035718, 0.1339889190003305, 0.13768064900068566]
merge_Laurent      [0.13691045599989593, 0.1544653910004854, 0.15945969300082652]
merge_Shihab       [0.13996293700074602, 0.14073836100033077, 0.15528064499994798]
merge_AlexL        [0.5525499420000415, 0.562283696999657, 0.954857885999445]
merge_EvKounis     [0.5699720739994518, 0.5713485720007156, 0.57778780100125]

List size = 15625, loops = 5
All functions verified True
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10786392400041223, 0.10926139099865395, 0.10992666599850054]
merge_vaultah      [0.12552327299999888, 0.1260173209993809, 0.126270750999538]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.13077028499901644, 0.13549192800019227, 0.13690466499974718]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.13939281700004358, 0.14145590299995092, 0.1771287490009854]
merge_Laurent      [0.14111154199963494, 0.141571592001128, 0.14596649399936723]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.14352190899990092, 0.1444555029993353, 0.1446186849989317]
merge_Shihab       [0.1475988830006827, 0.14831254499949864, 0.15240716699918266]
merge_AlexL        [2.040518506999433, 2.0523803409996617, 2.1246015890010312]
merge_EvKounis     [2.0611778700003924, 2.0809960999995383, 2.0933345120010927]
```

**Python 2 output**

```
Testing all functions with the question data
Expected: ['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
merge_wwii_ifelse True
merge_wwii_andor True
merge_PM2R_it True
merge_PM2R_pop True
merge_AlexL True
merge_Laurent True
merge_Shihab True
merge_EvKounis True
merge_vaultah True

List size = 5, loops = 15625
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.13266801834106445, 0.13341188430786133, 0.14590716361999512]
merge_vaultah      [0.1372370719909668, 0.20317387580871582, 0.28184700012207031]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.1373291015625, 0.14022302627563477, 0.14162182807922363]
merge_Shihab       [0.14127588272094727, 0.14717292785644531, 0.15103507041931152]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.16237378120422363, 0.16309309005737305, 0.1668241024017334]
merge_Laurent      [0.18718504905700684, 0.21074390411376953, 0.24513697624206543]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.28445720672607422, 0.29493808746337891, 0.32616496086120605]
merge_EvKounis     [0.29379916191101074, 0.33054614067077637, 0.34055399894714355]
merge_AlexL        [0.29791903495788574, 0.29801201820373535, 0.31824994087219238]

List size = 25, loops = 3125
All functions verified True
merge_vaultah      [0.10121989250183105, 0.10190892219543457, 0.10230588912963867]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.10298919677734375, 0.10324811935424805, 0.1042180061340332]
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.10428714752197266, 0.1065058708190918, 0.13893890380859375]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.11803603172302246, 0.11927890777587891, 0.12329411506652832]
merge_Shihab       [0.12048506736755371, 0.1209111213684082, 0.14031100273132324]
merge_Laurent      [0.12093997001647949, 0.12250900268554688, 0.12366700172424316]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.14476203918457031, 0.14788198471069336, 0.15009903907775879]
merge_AlexL        [0.2096550464630127, 0.2101140022277832, 0.21013402938842773]
merge_EvKounis     [0.22748994827270508, 0.24114799499511719, 0.27338886260986328]

List size = 125, loops = 625
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.093290090560913086, 0.095035076141357422, 0.10503697395324707]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.095438957214355469, 0.096124887466430664, 0.096685171127319336]
merge_vaultah      [0.096237897872924805, 0.096857070922851562, 0.10109710693359375]
merge_Laurent      [0.11233901977539062, 0.11253595352172852, 0.11261391639709473]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.11286282539367676, 0.11314296722412109, 0.11331295967102051]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.11631202697753906, 0.11657595634460449, 0.11874699592590332]
merge_Shihab       [0.12019991874694824, 0.12040495872497559, 0.12069797515869141]
merge_AlexL        [0.21399688720703125, 0.21718001365661621, 0.23727011680603027]
merge_EvKounis     [0.22643208503723145, 0.22728395462036133, 0.22952795028686523]

List size = 625, loops = 125
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.091418981552124023, 0.091669797897338867, 0.097893953323364258]
merge_vaultah      [0.092507839202880859, 0.09267878532409668, 0.09857487678527832]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.094152212142944336, 0.094262123107910156, 0.095048904418945312]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10612797737121582, 0.10874819755554199, 0.15479302406311035]
merge_Laurent      [0.10751605033874512, 0.10817885398864746, 0.1108400821685791]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.10856819152832031, 0.10870695114135742, 0.10909485816955566]
merge_Shihab       [0.12109684944152832, 0.12231802940368652, 0.12318301200866699]
merge_AlexL        [0.26717281341552734, 0.27173185348510742, 0.27331304550170898]
merge_EvKounis     [0.27798080444335938, 0.27915000915527344, 0.28347897529602051]

List size = 3125, loops = 25
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.089553117752075195, 0.090708017349243164, 0.096336126327514648]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.092846870422363281, 0.092998027801513672, 0.09307098388671875]
merge_vaultah      [0.093343973159790039, 0.096785068511962891, 0.11030793190002441]
merge_Laurent      [0.10524392127990723, 0.10576510429382324, 0.10692310333251953]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.10529899597167969, 0.10684394836425781, 0.1188349723815918]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.1075129508972168, 0.1087181568145752, 0.11004185676574707]
merge_Shihab       [0.12116694450378418, 0.1221461296081543, 0.12650799751281738]
merge_AlexL        [0.57863092422485352, 0.58119797706604004, 0.62129878997802734]
merge_EvKounis     [0.59500694274902344, 0.59542298316955566, 0.59793877601623535]

List size = 15625, loops = 5
All functions verified True
merge_wwii_ifelse  [0.093538999557495117, 0.094748973846435547, 0.099496126174926758]
merge_wwii_andor   [0.097050189971923828, 0.097167015075683594, 0.14334392547607422]
merge_vaultah      [0.097479820251464844, 0.097939968109130859, 0.10231399536132812]
merge_Laurent      [0.10894298553466797, 0.10906291007995605, 0.11107587814331055]
merge_PM2R_pop     [0.11378717422485352, 0.11389708518981934, 0.11422491073608398]
merge_PM2R_it      [0.11379504203796387, 0.1164860725402832, 0.11690497398376465]
merge_Shihab       [0.12729287147521973, 0.12743711471557617, 0.12863397598266602]
merge_AlexL        [2.062777042388916, 2.0632898807525635, 2.104421854019165]
merge_EvKounis     [2.0776879787445068, 2.1075038909912109, 2.1273050308227539]
```

These results are from my rather ancient 32 bit single-core 2GHZ machine with 2GB of RAM running a Debian derivative of Linux.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> lyst = [True,True,False,True,False]
>>> car = ['BMW','VW','Volvo']
>>> a = ['b', 'c']
>>> [car.pop(0) if item else a.pop(0) for item in lyst]
['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
>>>
```

Comment: if sum(lyst) <=  len(car) and (len(lyst)-sum(lyst)) <= len(a)

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea is to use a `dict` to choose between the `True` values (*car*) and the `False` values (*a*).

Since, the values are in order, you can make an iteration.

Here is a solution which use `iter()` and `next()` functions which are efficient:

```
lyst = [True, True, False, True, False]
car = ['BMW', 'VW', 'Volvo']
a = ['b', 'c']

selector = {True: iter(car), False: iter(a)}
result = [next(selector[flag]) for flag in lyst]
print(result)
# -> ['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
```

You can generalize this solution if you have more complex choices than True/False.

Comment: I found the term "selector" better than "dispatcher". So I replace mine.

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Code by @Alex is a great one, but complexity is a little bad due to that pop(0) operation. To avoid that-`

```
>>> lyst = [True,True,False,True,False]
>>> car = ['BMW','VW','Volvo']
>>> a = ['b', 'c']
>>> i=0
>>> j=0
>>> ans=[]
>>> for v in lyst:
        if v:
            ans.append(car[i])
            i+=1
        else:
            ans.append(a[j])
            j+=1


>>> ans
['BMW', 'VW', 'b', 'Volvo', 'c']
```

As for other answers, I am a bit surprised to see the use of all those complex syntax and data structures for such a simple task.

Comment: Using `iter` and `next` isn't _that_ complex. And Pythonistas go to great lengths to avoid accessing lists via indices, unless it's unavoidable. ;)

Comment: I am still a bit newbie to know, what is wrong with accessing list via index?

Comment: FWIW, another way to avoid the inefficiency of `.pop(0)` is to iterate over `reversed(lyst)` and `pop()` from the other 2 lists. Then you have to reverse the resulting list, of course, but that's reasonably efficient (certainly more efficient than creating the result list by pre-pending).

Comment: Oh, there's nothing _wrong_ with indirect access via indices, but using indices generally adds clutter to the code, and is less efficient than directly iterating. Using a `range` to produce the indices isn't too bad because it does its arithmetic at C speed, but maintaining the indices yourself with Python arithmetic, like `i+=1`, is relatively slow.

Comment: Now that's hell of an optimization.

Comment: I agree that it's good to give an answer that uses basic syntax, which is why I upvoted this answer. OTOH, the `next` function (or more precisely the `.__next__` or `.next` method that it calls) is a _very_ fundamental thing in Python: it's the basis of every `for` loop. The `for` syntax hides the `next` and `iter` stuff from you, but it's still there, lurking just below the surface.

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer. You should be pleased to see that your algorithm is the fastest on average for small lists in Python 3. For large lists, you get the problem of the slowness of Python arithmetic that I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option much like the one from @AlexL but with the `if` statements replaced by a dictionary look-up.

```
car = ["BMW", "VW", "Volvo"]
a = ["b", "c"]

my_list = [True, True, False, True, False]
mapping = {True: car, False: a}

new_list = [mapping[c].pop(0) for c in my_list]
```

Comment: You may be interested in the timing script & data I just added to my answer.